# How to get the part of the string before "|"

Tags: r, web-scraping, substring, str-replace

In my web scraping exercise, I have come up with a peculiar form of string given by -

```
st<-c("Samsung Galaxy M21 2021 Edition (Charcoal black , 6GB RAM, 128GB Storage) | FHD+ sAMOLED | 6 Months Free Screen Replacement for Prime")
```

And I want the part of the string before `"|"` i.e., I want the output as:

> "Samsung Galaxy M21 2021 Edition (Charcoal black , 6GB RAM, 128GB
> Storage)"

I am trying as `s <- st %>% str_replace("|.*","")`
but didn't get any improvement over "st"(defined above)

Comment: try this instead of `|.*`:
`\|.*$`

Comment: What's the website? There may be a better way to get the string you are after. How are you getting the result you show above?

Comment: Actually, this is one of the names of the phone I found when I search "Realme Mobile Phones" on amazon. in. There only a few names are in that form. For more details you can visit: https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Realme+Mobile+Phones&ref=nb_sb_noss_2

Comment: you may see this post for idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661012/r-remove-string-before-delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try -

```
st<-c("Samsung Galaxy M21 2021 Edition (Charcoal black , 6GB RAM, 128GB Storage) | FHD+ sAMOLED | 6 Months Free Screen Replacement for Prime")

sub('\\s*\\|.*', '', st)
#[1] "Samsung Galaxy M21 2021 Edition (Charcoal black , 6GB RAM, 128GB Storage)"
```